# Convert user input into integer in array in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods, refactoring

I want a user's input to become an integer that is the [0] index in a new array that I want to add more items to later. Is there a way to just convert the user's input into an array without changing it into an integer and pushing it? This is my current code:

```
guesses = []
puts "Guess what number I'm thinking of. It's between 1 and #{solution_range}"
guess = gets.to_i
guesses.push(guess)
```

Comment: You do have to convert to integer if you want it to be an integer (`gets` will return `String`). You could shorten your code to `guesses << gets.to_i` and get the same result.

Comment: `guesses = [gets.to_i]` perhaps.

Comment: You can assign the result of a method chain (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43751234/1301972) below), but generally readability trumps cleverness. YMMV.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 Assigning the literal the way you suggest will work, but using Kernel#Integer is safer than String#to_i. So, `guesses = [Integer(gets)]` is probably the better alternative if you're just looking for the shortest code that guarantees a single-element array and want to avoid chaining methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use Strict Casting

You *have* to cast your input to an Integer, because [Kernel#gets](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) always returns either a String or nil. One way to do this as a one-liner is to assign an empty Hash to your variable, and then append the cast to the Hash. This is probably faster than your current approach, but I haven't actually benchmarked it.

For example, if you enter `1` at the prompt, you will get:

```
print 'Enter integer: '
guesses = [] << Integer(gets)
#=> [1]
```

A nice side effect of this approach is that you'll get an appropriate exception if you can't cast the integer with [Kernel#Integer](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer). For example:

> Enter integer: foo
>   ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "foo\n"

### Avoid String#to_i When You Need a Strict Cast

Using [String#to_i](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-to_i) will not always do what you expect. Consider the following, assuming you enter `foo` at the prompt:

```
print 'Enter integer: '
guesses = [] << gets.to_i
#=> [0]
```

Because String#to_i is more lenient about the cast than Kernel#Integer, any non-integer response (including nil) will be cast as `0`. There may be times when this is what you want, but for your posted use case this is unlikely to be desirable.

Comment: Not just `guesses = [Integer(gets)]`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland You can if you want. But why do you think that's more explicit or more readable?